# How to log/query historic Azure Quotas?

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

We are using Azure Databricks to spin up multiple Job clusters during our Production runs, and we need to run more scripts at the same time; however, the organization has defined Quota limits for each Family of Computes, and we have thresholds we do want to cross.

We can check the current status of the Quota through the Azure Portal > Quotas > Computes. However, it only shows the current Quota status and there is no option to check the logs of historic quota utilization.

After a given run, we want to check the Quota usage during the run, and map Quota usage peaks with script runtimes. Right now, we have to keep checking the Quota Page manually continuously and log it manually somewhere like an excel to get a rough idea.

Is there a better way to log and query the Quota Usage history?

Answer (score 1):

You might looking for getting VM usage quota which you can  get for example from
[Get-AzVMUsage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quotas)

It provides you list of current usage for different compute families:
[image]

Comment: This will show the current usage too, I want to log it somewhere, without making a herculean task out of it like sending this to Event Hubs and then processing it and saving it somewhere.

Comment: @AnirbanSaha you may collect data and forward them to  Log Analytics Workspace Custom Log table and query it whenever you need. would that work for you  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/tutorial-custom-logs ?